# Correlation (and significance test) with ordinal predictor and continuous response

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, ordinal-data, kendall-tau

I am looking to correlate an ordinal variable (four categories) with a continuous variable (not normal). The dataset is large, around n=700. I am currently using Kendall's Tau-b because Goodman-Kruskal does not handle continuous data very well. Is there an appropriate correlation coefficient for this case?

Alternatively, should I apply multilevel models to this problem? As described here: [How to correctly assess the correlation between ordinal and a continuous variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78517/how-to-correctly-assess-the-correlation-between-ordinal-and-a-continuous-variabl)

Lastly, is this better conceived of as a matter of inference, i.e. asking whether the means of the four categories (say they are called 1,2,3, and 4) roughly follow the following pattern: 4>3>2>1? If this is the case, what statistic should I use to measure how closely the data follows that pattern, and how should I simulate the null distribution?

Comment: You have multiple questions here that are difficult to address without more information about your problem. Your last three sentences are particularly hard to follow and don't obviously connect to the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. I've made some changes. How does it look now?